# Learning Ruby: recommended blogs to read?

Tags: ruby, blogs

I'm about to start learning Ruby and would like a bit of reading material to help me into it.

I'm looking for your **top 5** blogs, news and any (active) bulletin boards (I can handle newsgroups fine, but I prefer reading in a BB) on Ruby.

Thanks,

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Reading blogs isn't the way to learn a programming language.  It might be useful *after* you learn the fundamentals of the language at which point you can:

1. Actually understand and make use of what you read on the blogs
2. Have the foundation necessary to weed out the good stuff from the bad stuff

I would recommend a good book to get you started, the recently released [The Ruby Programming Language](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596516177) is probably the best one out now.

Comment: I understand that, I just like to get a good 'feel' of what the communty is like as I learn. Thanks for that book.

Comment: To be perfectly honest, much of the Ruby user community is composed of newbies (due largely to recent explosion of growth and people using it for specific purposes (like building websites) without learning the full language) making it even more important to build a strong foundation first.

Answer (score 7):

@Robert I agree with you to stay away from feeds.  Its better to read a book and gain some in-depth knowledge....

However here are some that might help (with Rails and Ruby):

http://www.buildingwebapps.com/podcasts (Rails)

http://www.peepcode.com (Rails)

http://www.learningrails.com (Rails)

http://www.railsenvy.com (Rails)

http://www.bofh.org.uk/articles/category/ruby (RUBY specific)

http://www.pragprog.com (ruby)

Answer (score 4):

I assume you already know about [why's poignant guide](http://poignantguide.net/ruby/), but just in case, it's a good starting point. That and the [pickaxe book](http://www.pragprog.com/titles/ruby/programming-ruby).

I know you asked for blogs etc, but those two are pretty much essential reading.

Answer (score 3):

[Ruby Flow](http://www.rubyflow.com)

[Ruby Inside](http://www.rubyinside.com)

Those two should get you started.  Take the advice from others and grab some books and just start hacking away.

Answer (score 2):

Blogs by Why. Oddball but brilliant:

http://hackety.org/

http://redhanded.hobix.com/

Answer (score 2):

you can start with the basis here: http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/documentation/
and then on www.rubyflow.com you will find every day several links to tutorial and news about Ruby.

Answer (score 2):

Not a blog, but a(nother) book.  You can read [Programming Ruby](http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/) for free online.

Answer (score 1):

why's poignant guide is great, so is the free online Programming Ruby.

They are what I'm reading right now.

Answer (score 1):

Hard to miss...

http://delicious.com/popular/ruby

http://delicious.com/popular/rails

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get a good feel for the community (which is the greatest thing about ruby), take a look at the following:

- John Nunemaker's [Rails Tips](http://railstips.org/) (really [good](http://www.rubyinside.com/top-ruby-blogger-of-2008-john-nunemaker-1410.html) blog)
- Dr Nic's [Blog](http://drnicwilliams.com/)
- Josh Susser's [has_many :through](http://blog.hasmanythrough.com/)
- Jamis Buck's [the { buckblogs :here}](http://weblog.jamisbuck.org/)
- David Heinemeier Hansson's [Loud Thinking](http://www.loudthinking.com/)

DHH's blog does not really give too much technical insite, but I feel it is really good to read if you want to understand the community.  Too many people refer to it when they are writing, plus his posts tend to be interesting (to me).

When bored I like to take a look at [Ruby Flow](http://www.rubyflow.com/) and [Ruby Inside](http://www.rubyinside.com), it is a great place to discover new blogs.