# What are some good Ruby on Rails blogs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I started learning Rails 6 months ago and so far I love the community behind it. There are plenty of forums and documentation resources available, but I haven't been able to find an instructional, consistently maintained instructional Rails blog. I love Ryan Bates' Railscasts but I would love to find another blog that has the same consistency or quality as his.

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: Nope. Sorry. There are no good RoR blogs. Just bad ones.

Comment: Related:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/402847/learning-ruby-recommended-blogs-to-read

Comment: Really the best RoR blog posts are why PHP still beats it hands down: <a href="http://shiflett.org/blog/2007/may/terry-chay-on-rails">http://shiflett.org/blog/2007/may/terry-chay-on-rails</a>

Comment: He's not asking why you think php beats rails. He's asking about what blogs you would recommend. Lets be constructive.

Comment: @Allyn - touche. Still doesn't change the fact that its a duplicate question though.

Comment: @gabriel1836 - Why do you consider this to be a duplicate question? The other post does have some links to Rails blogs but Ruby and Rails are not synonymous. I would be like labeling a question on django as a duplicate of a python question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are hundreds and hundreds of good rails blogs.

Here is the OPML from my Google Reader Ruby on Rails section:

```
            <outline text="3DM Design" title="3DM Design" type="rss"
                xmlUrl="http://3dmdesign.com/dev-journal/feed" htmlUrl="http://dev-journal.3dmdesign.com"/>
            <outline
                text="&lt;3! â€” Chris Kampmeier on Ruby, Rails, and other delights"
                title="&lt;3! â€” Chris Kampmeier on Ruby, Rails, and other delights"
                type="rss"
                xmlUrl="http://feeds.feedburner.com/shiftcommathree-blog" htmlUrl="http://www.shiftcommathree.com/"/>
            <outline text="A Rubyist Railstastic Adventure"
                title="A Rubyist Railstastic Adventure" type="rss"
                xmlUrl="http://rubyist.tumblr.com/rss" htmlUrl="http://rubyist.tumblr.com/"/>
            <outline text="A Single Programmer's Blog - Home"
                title="A Single Programmer's Blog - Home" type="rss"
                xmlUrl="http://feeds.feedburner.com/teksol" htmlUrl="http://blog.teksol.info/"/>
            <outline text="a tornado of razorblades"
                title="a tornado of razorblades" type="rss"
                xmlUrl="http://adam.blog.heroku.com/feed" htmlUrl="http://www.google.com/reader/view/feed%2Fhttp%3A%2F%2Fadam.blog.heroku.com%2Ffeed"/>
            <outline text="Accelerate HR Blog"
                title="Accelerate HR Blog" type="rss"
                xmlUrl="http://www.jobwd.com/article/rss" htmlUrl="http://www.jobwd.com/article/rss"/>
            <outline text="Active Reload - Home"
                title="Active Reload - Home" type="rss"
                xmlUrl="http://feeds.feedburner.com/activereload" htmlUrl="http://hoth.entp.com/"/>
            <outline text="Addicted To New by John Nunemaker"
                title="Addicted To New by John Nunemaker" type="rss"
                xmlUrl="http://addictedtonew.com/feed/" htmlUrl="http://addictedtonew.com"/>
            <outline text="AirBlog - Home" title="AirBlog - Home"
                type="rss"
                xmlUrl="http://blog.airbladesoftware.com/feed/atom.xml" htmlUrl="http://blog.airbladesoftware.com/"/>
            <outline text="Alex Young's weblog"
                title="Alex Young's weblog" type="rss"
                xmlUrl="http://feeds.feedburner.com/webdevelopernotes" htmlUrl="http://alexyoung.org"/>
            <outline text="Alloy Code - Home" title="Alloy Code - Home"
                type="rss" xmlUrl="http://alloycode.com/feed/atom.xml" htmlUrl="http://www.alloycode.com/"/>
            <outline text="almost effortless" title="almost effortless"
                type="rss"
                xmlUrl="http://feeds.feedburner.com/almosteffortless" htmlUrl="http://almosteffortless.com"/>
            <outline text="AlternateIdea - Home"
                title="AlternateIdea - Home" type="rss"
                xmlUrl="http://feeds.feedburner.com/encytemedia" htmlUrl="http://alternateidea.com/"/>
            <outline text="Ambethia" title="Ambethia" type="rss"
                xmlUrl="http://ambethia.com/feed/atom/" htmlUrl="http://ambethia.com/"/>
            <outline text="Anarchogeek - Home"
                title="Anarchogeek - Home" type="rss"
                xmlUrl="http://www.anarchogeek.com/feed/atom.xml" htmlUrl="http://anarchogeek.com/"/>
            <outline text="and another thing..."
                title="and another thing..." type="rss"
                xmlUrl="http://pivotallabs.com/users/jsusser/blog.rss" htmlUrl="http://pivotallabs.com/users/jsusser/blog"/>
            <outline text="Andrzej on Software"
                title="Andrzej on Software" type="rss"
                xmlUrl="http://andrzejonsoftware.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default" htmlUrl="http://andrzejonsoftware.blogspot.com/"/>
            <outline text="Application Error" title="Application Error"
                type="rss"
                xmlUrl="http://feeds.feedburner.com/ApplicationError" htmlUrl="http://application-error.com/"/>
            <outline text="Article RSS Feed" title="Article RSS Feed"
                type="rss" xmlUrl="http://lrug.org/rss/meetings" htmlUrl="http://lrug.org/meetings/"/>
            <outline text="Article RSS Feed" title="Article RSS Feed"
                type="rss" xmlUrl="http://lrug.org/rss/" htmlUrl="http://lrug.org/"/>
            <outline text="Article RSS Feed" title="Article RSS Feed"
                type="rss" xmlUrl="http://lrug.org/rss/nights/" htmlUrl="http://lrug.org/nights/"/>
            <outline text="Astrails" title="Astrails" type="rss"
                xmlUrl="http://feeds.feedburner.com/Astrails" htmlUrl="http://blog.astrails.com/"/>
            <outline text="atomic_spin" title="atomic_spin" type="rss"
                xmlUrl="http://feeds.feedburner.com/atomic_spin" htmlUrl="http://spin.atomicobject.com/"/>
            <outline text="Badpopcorn" title="Badpopcorn" type="rss"
                xmlUrl="http://badpopcorn.com/blog/feed/atom/" htmlUrl="http://badpopcorn.com/blog"/>
            <outline text="Bambinos" title="Bambinos" type="rss"
                xmlUrl="http://feeds.feedburner.com/bambinos" htmlUrl="http://bambinos.tumblr.com/"/>
            <outline text="Bamboo Blog - Home"
                title="Bamboo Blog - Home" type="rss"
                xmlUrl="http://feeds.feedburner.com/newbamboo" htmlUrl="http://blog.new-bamboo.co.uk"/>
            <outline text="Barking Iguana" title="Barking Iguana"
                type="rss"
                xmlUrl="http://feeds.feedburner.com/BarkingIguana" htmlUrl="http://barkingiguana.com/?source=feed"/>
            <outline text="Beautiful Pixel - Home"
                title="Beautiful Pixel - Home" type="rss"
                xmlUrl="http://feeds.feedburner.com/BeautifulPixel" htmlUrl="http://beautifulpixel.com/"/>
            <outline text="Beech Bonanza" title="Beech Bonanza"
                type="rss"
                xmlUrl="http://www.shaneharvie.com/feeds/posts/default" htmlUrl="http://www.shaneharvie.com/"/>
            <outline text="BenCurtis.com" title="BenCurtis.com"
                type="rss"
                xmlUrl="http://feeds.feedburner.com/bencurtis" htmlUrl="http://www.bencurtis.com"/>
            <outline text="Binary Code" title="Binary Code" type="rss"
                xmlUrl="http://www.postal-code.com/binarycode/feed/atom/" htmlUrl="http://www.postal-code.com/binarycode"/>
            <outline text="Biodegradable Geek"
                title="Biodegradable Geek" type="rss"
                xmlUrl="http://feeds.feedburner.com/BiodegradableGeek" htmlUrl="http://biodegradablegeek.com"/>
            <outline text="bitfluent" title="bitfluent" type="rss"
                xmlUrl="http://feeds.feedburner.com/bitfluent" htmlUrl="http://blog.bitfluent.com/"/>
            <outline text="bl.ogtastic - Home"
                title="bl.ogtastic - Home" type="rss"
                xmlUrl="http://b.logi.cx/feed/atom.xml" htmlUrl="http://b.logi.cx/"/>
            <outline text="BlogFish - Blog" title="BlogFish - Blog"
                type="rss"
                xmlUrl="http://blog.innerewut.de/feed/atom.xml" htmlUrl="http://blog.innerewut.de/"/>
            <outline text="Bloggitation - Home"
                title="Bloggitation - Home" type="rss"
                xmlUrl="http://blog.zhekov.net/feed/atom.xml" htmlUrl="http://blog.zhekov.net/"/>
            <outline text="Brainspl.at" title="Brainspl.at" type="rss"
                xmlUrl="http://brainspl.at/xml/rss20/feed.xml" htmlUrl="http://brainspl.at/"/>
            <outline text="BrightBlog" title="BrightBlog" type="rss"
                xmlUrl="http://feeds.feedburner.com/Brightblog" htmlUrl="http://blog.brightbox.co.uk"/>
            <outline
                text="Bruce Williamsâ€”Ruby, Rails, and Design - Home"
                title="Bruce Williamsâ€”Ruby, Rails, and Design - Home"
                type="rss" xmlUrl="http://codefluency.com/feed/atom.xml" htmlUrl="http://codefluency.com/"/>
            <outline text="BuildingWebApps Articles"
                title="BuildingWebApps Articles" type="rss"
                xmlUrl="http://feeds.feedburner.com/buildingwebappsarticles" htmlUrl="/feeds/articles"/>
            <outline text="cfis" title="cfis" type="rss"
                xmlUrl="http://cfis.savagexi.com/xml/atom/feed.xml" htmlUrl="http://cfis.savagexi.com"/>
            <outline text="chris blogs" title="chris blogs" type="rss"
                xmlUrl="http://chneukirchen.org/blog/index.rss" htmlUrl="http://chneukirchen.org/blog"/>
            <outline text="coderrr" title="coderrr" type="rss"
                xmlUrl="http://coderrr.wordpress.com/feed/" htmlUrl="http://coderrr.wordpress.com"/>
            <outline text="Cody Fauser - Show all"
                title="Cody Fauser - Show all" type="rss"
                xmlUrl="http://feeds.feedburner.com/codyfauser" htmlUrl="http://www.codyfauser.com/"/>
            <outline text="Comments on: Bort - A Base Rails Application"
                title="Comments on: Bort - A Base Rails Application"
                type="rss"
                xmlUrl="http://jimneath.org/2008/09/09/bort-base-rails-application/feed/" htmlUrl="http://jimneath.org/2008/09/09/bort-base-rails-application/"/>
            <outline text="Continuous Thinking - Home"
                title="Continuous Thinking - Home" type="rss"
                xmlUrl="http://www.continuousthinking.com/feed/atom.xml" htmlUrl="http://continuousthinking.com/"/>
            <outline text="CrazyRails ~ Flex on Ruby on Rails"
                title="CrazyRails ~ Flex on Ruby on Rails" type="rss"
                xmlUrl="http://crazyrails.com/feed/atom/" htmlUrl="http://crazyrails.com/"/>
            <outline text="Dan Grigsby" title="Dan Grigsby" type="rss"
                xmlUrl="http://www.unpossible.com/feed/" htmlUrl="http://www.unpossible.com"/>
            <outline text="Dan Manges" title="Dan Manges" type="rss"
                xmlUrl="http://feeds.feedburner.com/dcmanges" htmlUrl="http://www.dcmanges.com/blog"/>
            <outline text="Daniel Fischer - Got Fisch?"
                title="Daniel Fischer - Got Fisch?" type="rss"
                xmlUrl="http://feeds.feedburner.com/Danielfischer" htmlUrl="http://www.danielfischer.com"/>
            <outline text="Darwinweb" title="Darwinweb" type="rss"
                xmlUrl="http://feeds.feedburner.com/darwinweb" htmlUrl="http://darwinweb.net/"/>
            <outline text="delynn - Home" title="delynn - Home"
                type="rss"
                xmlUrl="http://feeds.feedburner.com/delynnberry" htmlUrl="http://delynnberry.com/"/>
            <outline text="Depixelate - Home" title="Depixelate - Home"
                type="rss"
                xmlUrl="http://feeds.feedburner.com/depixelate" htmlUrl="http://www.depixelate.com/"/>
            <outline
                text="DEV_MEM.dump_to(:blog) - Multimedia systems blog"
                title="DEV_MEM.dump_to(:blog) - Multimedia systems blog"
                type="rss" xmlUrl="http://blog.mmediasys.com/feed/atom/" htmlUrl="http://blog.mmediasys.com/"/>
            <outline text="DevChix" title="DevChix" type="rss"
                xmlUrl="http://feeds.feedburner.com/devchix/QbOG" htmlUrl="http://www.devchix.com"/>
            <outline text="DevFi :" title="DevFi :" type="rss"
                xmlUrl="http://devfi.com/articles.atom" htmlUrl="http://devfi.com"/>
            <outline text="Dr Nic" title="Dr Nic" type="rss"
                xmlUrl="http://feeds.feedburner.com/DrNic" htmlUrl="http://drnicwilliams.com"/>
            <outline text="dweebd" title="dweebd" type="rss"
                xmlUrl="http://feeds.feedburner.com/dweebd" htmlUrl="http://www.dweebd.com"/>
            <outline text="EdgeCase - Home" title="EdgeCase - Home"
                type="rss" xmlUrl="http://feeds.feedburner.com/edgecase" htmlUrl="http://blog.edgecase.com/"/>
            <outline text="Ed's Elite blog" title="Ed's Elite blog"
                type="rss"
                xmlUrl="http://feeds.feedburner.com/EdSpencer" htmlUrl="http://edspencer.net/"/>
            <outline text="eigenclass" title="eigenclass" type="rss"
                xmlUrl="http://eigenclass.org/hiki.rb?c=rss;tags=blog" htmlUrl="http://eigenclass.org"/>
            <outline text="El Humidor" title="El Humidor" type="rss"
                xmlUrl="http://feeds.feedburner.com/ElHumidor" htmlUrl="http://elhumidor.blogspot.com/"/>
            <outline text="EleventyTen - Home"
                title="EleventyTen - Home" type="rss"
                xmlUrl="http://blog.eleventyten.com/feed/atom.xml" htmlUrl="http://blog.eleventyten.com"/>
            <outline text="Ereblog" title="Ereblog" type="rss"
                xmlUrl="http://www.erebor.com/feed/" htmlUrl="http://www.erebor.com"/>
            <outline text="Err the Blog - Home"
                title="Err the Blog - Home" type="rss"
                xmlUrl="http://feeds.feedburner.com/errtheblog" htmlUrl="http://errtheblog.com/"/>
            <outline text="Euruko 2009 Barcelona 9-10 May"
                title="Euruko 2009 Barcelona 9-10 May" type="rss"
                xmlUrl="http://euruko2009.org/rss" htmlUrl="http://euruko2009.org"/>
            <outline text="evan.musing" title="evan.musing" type="rss"
                xmlUrl="http://blog.fallingsnow.net/feed/" htmlUrl="http://blog.fallingsnow.net"/>
            <outline text="Fair Answers" title="Fair Answers" type="rss"
                xmlUrl="http://www.blog.fairanswers.com/?feed=rss2" htmlUrl="http://www.blog.fairanswers.com"/>
            <outline text="fairleads" title="fairleads" type="rss"
                xmlUrl="http://fairleads.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default" htmlUrl="http://fairleads.blogspot.com/"/>
            <outline text="five pound app" title="five pound app"
                type="rss" xmlUrl="http://fivepoundapp.com/meetup/next/" htmlUrl="http://fivepoundapp.com/"/>
            <outline text="FiveRuns Blog - Home"
                title="FiveRuns Blog - Home" type="rss"
                xmlUrl="http://blog.fiveruns.com/feed/atom.xml" htmlUrl="http://blog.fiveruns.com/"/>
            <outline text="Free Ruby and Rails Screencasts"
                title="Free Ruby and Rails Screencasts" type="rss"
                xmlUrl="http://feeds.feedburner.com/rubyplus" htmlUrl="http://www.rubyplus.org/episodes.rss"/>
            <outline text="Freelancing Gods" title="Freelancing Gods"
                type="rss"
                xmlUrl="http://feeds.feedburner.com/freelancing_gods" htmlUrl="http://freelancing-gods.com"/>
            <outline text="geek!daily" title="geek!daily" type="rss"
                xmlUrl="http://feeds.feedburner.com/geekdailyblog" htmlUrl="http://blog.geekdaily.org/"/>
            <outline text="Geoff Evason" title="Geoff Evason" type="rss"
                xmlUrl="http://feeds.feedburner.com/GeoffEvason" htmlUrl="http://geoff.evason.name"/>
            <outline
                text="GIANT ROBOTS SMASHING INTO OTHER GIANT ROBOTS - Home"
                title="GIANT ROBOTS SMASHING INTO OTHER GIANT ROBOTS - Home"
                type="rss"
                xmlUrl="http://feeds.feedburner.com/GiantRobotsSmashingIntoOtherGiantRobots" htmlUrl="http://giantrobots.thoughtbot.com/"/>
            <outline text="Giles Bowkett" title="Giles Bowkett"
                type="rss"
                xmlUrl="http://feeds.feedburner.com/gilesbowkett" htmlUrl="http://gilesbowkett.blogspot.com/"/>
            <outline text="Gluttonous" title="Gluttonous" type="rss"
                xmlUrl="http://feeds.feedburner.com/Gluttonous" htmlUrl="http://glu.ttono.us/"/>
            <outline text="Grasp Ruby on Rails - Blog"
                title="Grasp Ruby on Rails - Blog" type="rss"
                xmlUrl="http://grasprubyonrails.com/feed/atom.xml" htmlUrl="http://grasprubyonrails.com/"/>
            <outline text="GrokBlok - Home" title="GrokBlok - Home"
                type="rss" xmlUrl="http://feeds.feedburner.com/grokblok" htmlUrl="http://www.google.com/reader/view/feed%2Fhttp%3A%2F%2Ffeeds.feedburner.com%2Fgrokblok"/>
            <outline text="gurge.com" title="gurge.com" type="rss"
                xmlUrl="http://gurge.com/blog/feed/" htmlUrl="http://gurge.com/blog"/>
            <outline text="Hampton Catlin - Home"
                title="Hampton Catlin - Home" type="rss"
                xmlUrl="http://hamptoncatlin.com/feed/atom.xml" htmlUrl="http://hamptoncatlin.com/"/>
            <outline
                text="has_many :bugs, :through =&amp;gt; :rails - Home"
                title="has_many :bugs, :through =&amp;gt; :rails - Home"
                type="rss"
                xmlUrl="http://feeds.feedburner.com/monkeyonrails" htmlUrl="http://m.onkey.org/"/>
            <outline text="has_many :through - home"
                title="has_many :through - home" type="rss"
                xmlUrl="http://feeds.feedburner.com/hasmanythrough" htmlUrl="http://blog.hasmanythrough.com"/>
            <outline text="Headius" title="Headius" type="rss"
                xmlUrl="http://headius.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default" htmlUrl="http://blog.headius.com/"/>
            <outline text="Headius" title="Headius" type="rss"
                xmlUrl="http://blog.headius.com/feeds/posts/default" htmlUrl="http://blog.headius.com/"/>
            <outline text="Heroku News" title="Heroku News" type="rss"
                xmlUrl="http://feeds.feedburner.com/heroku" htmlUrl="http://blog.heroku.com"/>
            <outline text="HeyCarsten - Home" title="HeyCarsten - Home"
                type="rss"
                xmlUrl="http://feeds.feedburner.com/heycarsten" htmlUrl="http://heycarsten.com/"/>
            <outline text="HickoryTech" title="HickoryTech" type="rss"
                xmlUrl="http://tech.hickorywind.org/articles.rss" htmlUrl="http://tech.hickorywind.org/articles.rss"/>
            <outline text="Hungry Machine Blog - All"
                title="Hungry Machine Blog - All" type="rss"
                xmlUrl="http://feeds.feedburner.com/hungrymachine" htmlUrl="http://blog.hungrymachine.com"/>
            <outline text="igvita.com" title="igvita.com" type="rss"
                xmlUrl="http://feeds.feedburner.com/igvita" htmlUrl="http://www.igvita.com"/>
            <outline text="In the Key of E" title="In the Key of E"
                type="rss"
                xmlUrl="https://blogs.oracle.com/emononen/feed/entries/atom?cat=%2FNetBeans" htmlUrl="https://blogs.oracle.com/emononen/"/>
            <outline text="interblah.net - blog"
                title="interblah.net - blog" type="rss"
                xmlUrl="http://interblah.net/feed.xml" htmlUrl="http://www.google.com/reader/view/feed%2Fhttp%3A%2F%2Finterblah.net%2Ffeed.xml"/>
            <outline text="Intridea - Blog" title="Intridea - Blog"
                type="rss"
                xmlUrl="http://www.intridea.com/feed/blog/atom.xml" htmlUrl="http://www.intridea.com/blog/company"/>
            <outline text="Inventive Labs: Weblog"
                title="Inventive Labs: Weblog" type="rss"
                xmlUrl="http://feeds.feedburner.com/inventivelabs-weblog" htmlUrl="http://www.google.com/reader/view/feed%2Fhttp%3A%2F%2Ffeeds.feedburner.com%2Finventivelabs-weblog"/>
            <outline text="Irene Ros - Blog" title="Irene Ros - Blog"
                type="rss"
                xmlUrl="http://ireneros.com/atom/?section=Blog" htmlUrl="http://ireneros.com/"/>
            <outline text="Jake Scruggs" title="Jake Scruggs" type="rss"
                xmlUrl="http://jakescruggs.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default" htmlUrl="http://jakescruggs.blogspot.com/"/>
            <outline text="James on Software - Home"
                title="James on Software - Home" type="rss"
                xmlUrl="http://feeds.feedburner.com/JamesOnSoftware" htmlUrl="http://jamesgolick.com/"/>
            <outline text="Jason Seifer" title="Jason Seifer" type="rss"
                xmlUrl="http://jasonseifer.com/feed" htmlUrl="http://jasonseifer.com"/>
            <outline text="Jay Fields Thoughts"
                title="Jay Fields Thoughts" type="rss"
                xmlUrl="http://blog.jayfields.com/feeds/posts/default" htmlUrl="http://blog.jayfields.com/"/>
            <outline text="jeremydurham.com" title="jeremydurham.com"
                type="rss"
                xmlUrl="http://www.jeremydurham.com/wordpress/wp-rss2.php" htmlUrl="http://www.jeremydurham.com"/>
            <outline text="Jicksta.com" title="Jicksta.com" type="rss"
                xmlUrl="http://feeds.feedburner.com/jicksta" htmlUrl="http://jicksta.com"/>
            <outline text="jlaine.net - Home" title="jlaine.net - Home"
                type="rss"
                xmlUrl="http://feeds.feedburner.com/jlainenet" htmlUrl="http://jlaine.net/"/>
            <outline text="John Lam on Software"
                title="John Lam on Software" type="rss"
                xmlUrl="http://feeds.feedburner.com/LessIsBetter" htmlUrl="http://www.iunknown.com/"/>
            <outline text="Jonathan.inspect" title="Jonathan.inspect"
                type="rss"
                xmlUrl="http://jonathan.tron.name/articles.atom" htmlUrl="http://jonathan.tron.name"/>
            <outline text="Journal" title="Journal" type="rss"
                xmlUrl="http://www.rorsecurity.info/journal/atom.xml" htmlUrl="http://www.rorsecurity.info/journal/"/>
            <outline text="Juixe TechKnow" title="Juixe TechKnow"
                type="rss"
                xmlUrl="http://www.juixe.com/techknow/index.php/feed/atom/" htmlUrl="http://www.juixe.com/techknow"/>
            <outline text="Koz Speaks - Home" title="Koz Speaks - Home"
                type="rss" xmlUrl="http://feeds.feedburner.com/Koz" htmlUrl="http://www.koziarski.net/"/>
            <outline text="LakTEK" title="LakTEK" type="rss"
                xmlUrl="http://feeds.feedburner.com/laktek-blog" htmlUrl="http://www.web2media.net/laktek"/>
            <outline text="Learning Rails" title="Learning Rails"
                type="rss"
                xmlUrl="http://feeds.feedburner.com/learning-rails" htmlUrl="http://www.learningrails.com/"/>
            <outline text="Libin Pan" title="Libin Pan" type="rss"
                xmlUrl="http://feeds.feedburner.com/LibinPan" htmlUrl="http://blog.libinpan.com"/>
            <outline text="LiquidRail - Rails"
                title="LiquidRail - Rails" type="rss"
                xmlUrl="http://liquidrail.com/feed/atom.xml" htmlUrl="http://liquidrail.com/"/>
            <outline text="Loud Thinking by David Heinemeier Hansson"
                title="Loud Thinking by David Heinemeier Hansson"
                type="rss"
                xmlUrl="http://feeds.feedburner.com/LoudThinking" htmlUrl="http://www.loudthinking.com/"/>
            <outline text="Luca Guidi - Home" title="Luca Guidi - Home"
                type="rss"
                xmlUrl="http://www.lucaguidi.com/feed/atom.xml" htmlUrl="http://lucaguidi.com/"/>
            <outline text="Lucky Sneaks - Blog"
                title="Lucky Sneaks - Blog" type="rss"
                xmlUrl="http://feeds.feedburner.com/luckysneaks" htmlUrl="/blog"/>
            <outline text="Magnus Holm" title="Magnus Holm" type="rss"
                xmlUrl="http://feeds.feedburner.com/MagnusHolm" htmlUrl="http://judofyr.net/"/>
            <outline text="Marc-Andre Cournoyer's Awesome Feed"
                title="Marc-Andre Cournoyer's Awesome Feed" type="rss"
                xmlUrl="http://macournoyer.com/blog.atom" htmlUrl="http://macournoyer.com"/>
            <outline text="Marc-AndrÃ© Cournoyer's blog"
                title="Marc-AndrÃ© Cournoyer's blog" type="rss"
                xmlUrl="http://macournoyer.wordpress.com/feed/" htmlUrl="http://macournoyer.wordpress.com"/>
            <outline text="MarcRic Blog" title="MarcRic Blog" type="rss"
                xmlUrl="http://marcricblog.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default" htmlUrl="http://marcricblog.blogspot.com/"/>
            <outline text="Martin's Blog" title="Martin's Blog"
                type="rss"
                xmlUrl="https://blogs.oracle.com/martink/feed/entries/rss" htmlUrl="https://blogs.oracle.com/martink/"/>
            <outline text="Matt, MS" title="Matt, MS" type="rss"
                xmlUrl="http://feeds.feedburner.com/MattMs" htmlUrl="http://blog.matt-darby.com"/>
            <outline text="Meme Agora" title="Meme Agora" type="rss"
                xmlUrl="http://memeagora.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default" htmlUrl="http://memeagora.blogspot.com/"/>
            <outline text="Mental Paging Space"
                title="Mental Paging Space" type="rss"
                xmlUrl="http://mentalpagingspace.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default" htmlUrl="http://mentalpagingspace.blogspot.com/"/>
            <outline text="Midnight Oil" title="Midnight Oil" type="rss"
                xmlUrl="http://feeds.feedburner.com/aisleten/blog" htmlUrl="http://blog.aisleten.com"/>
            <outline text="Mike Clark" title="Mike Clark" type="rss"
                xmlUrl="http://www.clarkware.com/cgi/blosxom/index.rss" htmlUrl="http://www.clarkware.com/cgi/blosxom"/>
            <outline text="mikhailian" title="mikhailian" type="rss"
                xmlUrl="http://mikhailian.livejournal.com/data/atom" htmlUrl="http://mikhailian.livejournal.com/"/>
            <outline text="Mister Bleigh - Blog"
                title="Mister Bleigh - Blog" type="rss"
                xmlUrl="http://feeds.feedburner.com/mbleigh/" htmlUrl="http://www.mbleigh.com/"/>
            <outline
                text="Mr. Matt - Ruby on Rails Developer, Manchester UK"
                title="Mr. Matt - Ruby on Rails Developer, Manchester UK"
                type="rss" xmlUrl="http://matthall.wordpress.com/feed/" htmlUrl="http://matthall.wordpress.com"/>
            <outline text="Mutually Human Software - Blog"
                title="Mutually Human Software - Blog" type="rss"
                xmlUrl="http://www.mutuallyhuman.com/feed/blog/atom.xml" htmlUrl="http://mutuallyhuman.com/blog"/>
            <outline
                text="nano RAILS: development, testing and hosting tidbits - Home"
                title="nano RAILS: development, testing and hosting tidbits - Home"
                type="rss"
                xmlUrl="http://feeds.feedburner.com/Nanorails" htmlUrl="http://blog.nanorails.com/"/>
            <outline text="NetBeans Wiki: RubyOnRails"
                title="NetBeans Wiki: RubyOnRails" type="rss"
                xmlUrl="http://wiki.netbeans.org/wiki/rss.jsp?page=RubyOnRails&amp;mode=wiki" htmlUrl="http://wiki.netbeans.org/"/>
            <outline text="Neverintheoffice.net - Home"
                title="Neverintheoffice.net - Home" type="rss"
                xmlUrl="http://neverintheoffice.net/feed/atom.xml" htmlUrl="http://neverintheoffice.net/"/>
            <outline text="Nimble Method" title="Nimble Method"
                type="rss" xmlUrl="http://feeds.feedburner.com/pluron" htmlUrl="http://blog.pluron.com/"/>
            <outline text="Nobody Listens Anyway"
                title="Nobody Listens Anyway" type="rss"
                xmlUrl="http://www.justinball.com/feed/" htmlUrl="http://www.justinball.com"/>
            <outline text="Not So Stupid" title="Not So Stupid"
                type="rss" xmlUrl="http://www.notsostupid.com/feed/" htmlUrl="http://www.notsostupid.com"/>
            <outline text="Notch8" title="Notch8" type="rss"
                xmlUrl="http://www.notch8.com/xml/atom/feed.xml" htmlUrl="http://www.notch8.com"/>
            <outline text="Nuby on Rails" title="Nuby on Rails"
                type="rss"
                xmlUrl="http://feeds.feedburner.com/nubyonrails" htmlUrl="http://nubyonrails.com"/>
            <outline text="Nuby on Rails" title="Nuby on Rails"
                type="rss"
                xmlUrl="http://nubyonrails.topfunky.com/xml/atom/feed.xml" htmlUrl="http://nubyonrails.com"/>
            <outline text="Nullcreations - Recent Entries"
                title="Nullcreations - Recent Entries" type="rss"
```

Comment: Whoa.  If you keep up with all that content you'll never have time to code.  :)

Comment: I just skim and open what i want to read in separate tabs and then post them to my delicious (srboisvert) and then eventually write a few lines of summary and post to my blog.  Mostly, it lets me know what is possible and what is available.  Doing stuff still requires research.

Answer (score 0):

I follow http://weblog.rubyonrails.org

Answer (score 0):

I used to follow many Rails blogs, but lately I just visit [Planet Ruby on Rails](http://www.planetrubyonrails.com/) a couple of times a day.  There is also a @rornews Twitter account that regularly posts interesting links.